# Firebase / Firestore: No document exists but it should

Tags: javascript, firebase, cordova, google-cloud-firestore

For console output from the `firestore` call, I am getting `No such document!`, even though there is a document there (I can see it in the firebase console). Here are some screenshots showing my `firestore` database:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    var db = firebase.firestore();

    // Disable deprecated features
    db.settings({
      timestampsInSnapshots: true
    });

    console.log("app.selectedPoolId:", app.selectedPoolId);

    db.collection("pools").doc(app.selectedPoolId).collection("items").doc("items_array").get()
        .then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                ...
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
app.selectedPoolId: Eamon's pool
```

This happens when I try to run my hybrid `ios/phonegap` app from `XCode` on a device. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I output the `doc` object's keys and values, just incase anyone notices anything weird.

This code:

```
for (var prop in doc) {
     console.log("doc key:", prop);
     console.log("doc value:", doc[prop]);
}
```

Produces this output:

```
2019-02-07 16:05:21.306952-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] app.selectedPoolId: Eamon's pool
2019-02-07 16:05:21.524750-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: _firestore
2019-02-07 16:05:21.524868-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: [object Object]
2019-02-07 16:05:21.524987-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: _key
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525044-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: pools/Eamon's pool/items/items_array
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525095-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: _document
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525133-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value:
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525171-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: _fromCache
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525208-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: false
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525274-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: _hasPendingWrites
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525388-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: false
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525435-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: data
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525512-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: function (t){return mr("DocumentSnapshot.data",arguments,0,1),t=lc("DocumentSnapshot.data",t),this._document?this.convertObject(this._document.data,ri.fromSnapshotOptions(t,this._firestore._areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled())):void 0}
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525561-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: get
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525624-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: function (t,e){if(mr("DocumentSnapshot.get",arguments,1,2),e=lc("DocumentSnapshot.get",e),this._document){var n=this._document.data.field(ju("DocumentSnapshot.get",t));if(void 0!==n)return this.convertValue(n,ri.fromSnapshotOptions(e,this._firestore._areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled()))}}
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525672-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: id
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525711-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: items_array
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525749-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: ref
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525818-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: [object Object]
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525857-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: exists
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525895-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: false
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525933-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: metadata
2019-02-07 16:05:21.525971-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: [object Object]
2019-02-07 16:05:21.526008-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: isEqual
2019-02-07 16:05:21.526232-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: function (e){if(!(e instanceof t))throw Nr("isEqual","DocumentSnapshot",1,e);return this._firestore===e._firestore&&this._fromCache===e._fromCache&&this._key.isEqual(e._key)&&(null===this._document?null===e._document:this._document.isEqual(e._document))}
2019-02-07 16:05:21.526289-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: convertObject
2019-02-07 16:05:21.526329-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: function (t,e){var n=this,r={};return t.forEach(function(t,i){r[t]=n.convertValue(i,e)}),r}
2019-02-07 16:05:21.526429-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: convertValue
2019-02-07 16:05:21.526496-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: function (t,e){if(t instanceof gi)return this.convertObject(t,e);if(t instanceof vi)return this.convertArray(t,e);if(t instanceof mi){var n=t.value(e),r=this._firestore.ensureClientConfigured().databaseId();return t.databaseId.isEqual(r)||$n("Document "+this._key.path+" contains a document reference within a different database ("+t.databaseId.projectId+"/"+t.databaseId.database+") which is not supported. It will be treated as a reference in the current database ("+r.projectId+"/"+r.database+") instead."),new rc(n,this._firestore)}return t.value(e)}
2019-02-07 16:05:21.526629-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc key: convertArray
2019-02-07 16:05:21.526713-0500 HybridPool[5063:1305478] doc value: function (t,e){var n=this;return t.internalValue.map(function(t){return n.convertValue(t,e)})}
```

**UPDATE**

I realized I could get the same document using `where` on it's `collection`, but when I try that - it acts as if the function never executes - no error messages, or any other kind of message - it stops after:

```
console.log("app.selectedPoolId:", app.selectedPoolId);
```

It outputs the same thing because of the above line, and then stops running without any errors, this is the code I am running to query the collection:

```
    db.collection("pools").where("name", "==", app.selectedPoolId).get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
```

Again, no output results form the above code.

Here are the `firestore` best practices - I looked through them and I think my code complies:

[Firestore Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure on this but the problem may be that the document name "Eamon's pool" has a space in it and so it not recognizing the whole thing or it is stopping at the first part of the string "Eamon's".

In the past, when I have used Firestore, the document names I have used contain no spaces and so having space could be the problem.

Try renaming the document to EamonsPool or a name with no space and try again.

Comment: i thought of this and tried with an entry that i created with no space, but it still couldnt find it...I'll try the backslash and see what happens...thanks

Comment: i created a ticket with firebase so ill see what they say, but this code was previously working...

Comment: it actually was the space...when i tested for without the space...i forgot to add the neccessary "fake" items for it to look for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get documents listed in my collection but getDocuments() func returned empty array all the time. But the documents existed in Firestore!

I have **fixed it by adding some property to the documents in that collection**. As shown on the screenshot. It can be any property with any value, it just should be there, otherwise you will get empty array in response.

I would like if Google would finally put it into getDocuments() func documentation so people would not be required to spend their time on such dummy issues generated by such implicit behaviours

[image: Property added to the document]